# Using aggregate functions in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have my Table structure like this ::

```
ATT_Table : Fields - Act_ID, Assigned_To_ID, Percent_Complete(Integer value)
Act_ID is primary key, Assigned_To_ID is referenced to Emp_ID in Employee_Table.

Employee_Table : Fields - Emp_ID, F_Name. 
Emp_ID is primary key.
```

Now at a particular point in time, 1 or more activities can be assigned to same person. My goal is write a query to calculate a person's load. I want to count the number of activities assigned to a particular person (can be more than 1) then take the average of their `percent_Complete`.

For example if person A is assigned A1, A2, A3(Act_ID). Then corresponding (Percent_Complete values addition)/3. Basically an average. In my final query result I want:

```
Name, Number of activities assigned(Count), load value(Avg).
```

How do I this? Do I have to use a nested `WHERE IN` clause ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

```
select Emp_ID, F_Name, count(Act_ID), avg(Percent_Complete)
from ATT_Table, Employee_Table where ATT_Table.Assigned_To_ID = Employee_Table.Emp_ID
group by Emp_ID, F_Name
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  MIN(F_Name) Employee_Name ,
        COUNT(1) Activities_Assigned ,
        AVG(Percent_Complete) Load_Value
FROM    ATT_Table a
        INNER JOIN Employee_Table e ON a.Assigned_To_ID = e.Emp_ID
GROUP BY e.Emp_ID
```

Answer (score 2):

I may be missing some nuance, but it sounds like you can just: join the tables, group by employee, `COUNT` and `AVG` for the load.

Answer (score 0):

As Dmitri said, something like

```
SELECT Employee_Table.F_Name, COUNT(*) AS activities, AVG(Percent_Complete) AS load
FROM ATT_Table JOIN Employee_Table ON ATT_Table.Assigned_to_ID = Employee_Table.Emp_ID
WHERE Employee_Table.Emp_ID = 42
GROUP BY Employee_Table.Emp_ID
```